# Admin->Synchronize Templates, show Only changed?

Tags: templates

How can I modify the code to show ONLY templates that have changed? I think it kind of ludicrous to show unchanged templates in the Synchronize Templates page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write an ExpressionEngine Accessory. Accessories allow you to inject code into Control Panel pages.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/accessories.html

Please go that route, and **not** the "let's edit core files derp derp" route. You can use this method to inject some jQuery using a function like this:

```
ee()->cp->add_to_foot('
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.class-of-unchanged-template-rows-goes-here').remove();
    });
</script>
');
```

This answer has a more thorough example of how an accessory is structured:

[Include custom JavaScript in the control panel](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15457/include-custom-javascript-in-the-control-panel)

Comment: Had to modify the javascript, see edited original post but got it working.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final working accessory for everyone to use. If you make mods, please post them here.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * ExpressionEngine Developer Accessory
 *
 * @package     Synch Templates fix
 * @category    Accessory
 * @description Shows only CHANGED templates in Synchronize templates view
 * @author      MB34
 */


class Synch_templates_acc
{
    var $name           = 'Fix Synch Templates';
    var $id             = 'default_value';
    var $version        = '1.0';
    var $description    = 'Shows only CHANGED templates in Synchronize templates view';
    var $sections       = array();

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->EE =& get_instance();
    } 

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
    * Set Sections
    */
    function set_sections()
    {
        // hide accessory from footer tabs
        $this->sections[] = '<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">$("#accessoryTabs a.default_value").parent().remove();</script>';

        // add css, js and html
        $this->EE->cp->add_to_foot('
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var table = document.getElementById("entries");
                for (var i = table.rows.length-1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i--) {
                    if(row.parentElement.nodeName != "THEAD") {
                        //iterate through rows
                        //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
                        col = row.cells[5];
                        if(col.firstChild && col.firstChild.nodeType != 3) {
                            if(col.firstChild.nodeName != "INPUT") {
                                row.remove();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }    
            });
        </script>
        ');
    }

}
// END CLASS

/* End of file acc.synch_templates.php */
/* Location: ./system/expressionengine/third_party/synch_templates/acc.synch_templates.php */
```